# Visual-Studio-2015 Cross-platform wstring not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wstring

[image]

Does anybody have any idea why my wstring functions might fail?
I don't!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Messed up h file? Wrong path to h file? Maybe my thinking is out of date. Don't use c++ any more.

Comment: @joshp Can you explain what you mean? You don't use c++ anymore and still cope with unicode strings?

Comment: I used to use C++. I thought maybe it's a bad path to an older h file, or maybe you're not using C++ 11 and/or .back really isn't available in your library version. But C++ is so long ago for me, I only had intuition about what might be wrong. I still work with unicode strings, but not in C++.